# Which sentence is grammatically correct for a song?

Tags: grammar

My question is, which of the following sentences(#**1** and #**2**) is grammatically correct? (This is part of a song's lyrics.)

> 1.You and me with empty hands.

Or

> 2.You and I with empty hands.

Comment: Depends on whether the context makes the pronouns the object or the subject of a verb. This is a sentence fragment and is thus ambiguous.

Comment: I dont understand your explanation, it complicates simple question. I looked up your point:   if a subject is singular, its verb must also be singular ( how this can be applicable here I have NO clue @Luke Sawczak

Comment: @millym Luke's answer was not about number at all. Do you understand the difference in meaning between "I love him" and "He loves me." In the first "I" is the subject of the verb "love." In the second "me" is the object of the verb "loves." However, your examples are not sentences at all because they contain no verb, and so either "I" or "me" is possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sentence fragment because it has no verb.

A verb has a subject and (often) an object.

Some personal pronouns change form depending on whether they are the subject or the object of a verb.

The difference between your two versions is that in one, the pronouns are the subject of a verb ("you and I"), but in the other, they are the object of a verb ("you and me").

Since this sentence has no verb, it's ambiguous.

To show you what I mean, both of these sets of lyrics are correct:

> We're standing there
>   
> You and I with empty hands
>
> In my memory I see us there
>   
> You and me with empty hands

In the first one, the pronouns are subjects. In the second one, the pronouns are objects.

With just the original fragment, we can't decide which they are. But the good news is: If the rest of the lyrics never fill in the gap, then it really doesn't matter which one you use.